# Can I use UITableviewCell like this?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview

Normally in a UITableView, we assign the value for the cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method which is the delegate method of UITableView. In this case, if we use a CustomTableViewCell, we assign the values in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = customTableViewCell;        
    }

    cell.label1.text = @"text1";
    cell.label2.text = @"text2";

    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}
```

This way of using CustomCell is a usual one. The texts will be displayed on the labels of the cell, but I need some clarification in using CustomCell in another way. I have a method in MainViewController like the following

```
- (void)methodInMainViewConroller {

        CustomCell *customCell = [[CustomCell alloc] init];
        [customCell methodInCustomCell];
        [tableView reloadData];

}
```

and in CustomCell, I have the definition for the method as

```
- (void)methodInCustomCell {

            self.label1.text = @"text1";
            self.label2.text = @"text2";

    }
```

Will this work? Will the text be displayed on the labels of the cell? Actually it doesn't work for me. Anyone help me to make this work perfectly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw, You should consider using an UINib object (if you have a lot of rows), it is slightly more efficient.

Comment: R u planning to call the methodInMainViewController from cellForRowAtIndexPath ? Is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
- (void)methodInMainViewConroller {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
    CustomCell *customCell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [customCell methodInCustomCell];
}
```

**UPDATE**: What I've just realized is that once you scroll the table view your labels will be reset to previous values. It might not work this way, but give it a try.

Comment: Well no. If you reload the table than the cell will be recreated so you will lose your changes that `methodInCustomCell` will do to it.

Comment: If I reload the table, the static name given in the xib appears. Any idea to bring the text instead?

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at your code. You never actually do anything with that cell once you set the labels. Anyway, how would the tableview know to use your cell and where to put it?

Comment: Ya. That is my problem. I do not know how to implement the second type perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the cell you `alloc/init` and work on is a totally different object. You can, however, store that cell as an ivar and always return that very cell for the given `indexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

This method don't work because you call it for just created custom cell not for cell in `tableView`.

You need something like this:

```
CustomCell *customCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[customCell methodInCustomCell];
```

Comment: If I reload the table, the static name given in the xib appears. Any idea to bring the text instead?

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = customCell;        
    }
    
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}

Comment: Where CustomCell is the class and customCell is the object of the CustomCell which is declared globally..